# How can I gather data from a file as an actual number instead of a string in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python and am attempting to make a small program to record changes in an amount of money. I can take the data from the file (Amount.txt) but I can not add or subtract from it. The program recognizes the numbers from Amount.txt as a string and not an actual number. I have attempted to use the int() command but I don’t know where I would put that command or if I even need it. When I use the int() command an error message stating, “TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'” How can I fix This?

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
def money(xy):
    f = open("Amount.txt", "r").read()
    newamount = add(f, xy)
    f = open("Amount.txt", "w").write(newamount)
    f.close
while True:
    dollars = open("Amount.txt", "r").read()
    print("Current Updated Total: ($" + dollars + ")")
    num = input("Transition: ")
    money(num)
```

I attempted to have the program ask the user for a number in which it would add to the total amount of money, and then rewrite Amount.txt to contain the new sum. For example, if the total was 5 and the user typed 5 then the new total would be 10. Amount.txt would also contain the number 10 instead of 5. However, the actual result looks like this: The total would be 5 and the user would type 5 and the new total would be 55. How can I fix this?

Comment: How is the ```Amount.txt``` file formatted? When you read files the content is a string type, and performing numeric operations requires you convert the string to an integer type first. Depending on the file format, there might be different methods of extracting the numeric string from other strings and finally being able to use the ```int()``` function on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Amount.txt` contains one integer number, *e.g.*, `42`, *cast* the string to an int using `int()`, as you mentioned:

```py
f = open("Amount.txt", "r").read()
f = int(f)
```

You're also opening the file several times, and it's probably not a bad idea to close it before re-opening with a different mode. Full script:

```py
def add(x, y):
        return x + y

def money(xy):
    fh = open("Amount.txt", "r")
    f = int(fh.read())
    fh.close()
    newamount = add(f, xy)
    fh = open("Amount.txt", "w")
    fh.write(str(newamount))
    fh.close()

while True:
    fh = open("Amount.txt", "r")
    dollars = int(fh.read())
    fh.close()
    print("Current Updated Total: (${0})".format(dollars))
    num = input("Transition: ")
    money(num)
```

Comment: Yes `Amount.txt` does olny contain one integer number. Assuming you ment adding the line `f = int(f)` after line 4, then this causes an error stating, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: That's because your code over-wrote `Amount.txt` with no data, so reading it produces the empty string `''`.